# Exception not being passed to my Error Page in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, error-handling, custom-errors

I've got my `customErrors` mode set to On and redirecting to:

[image]

Here's my view in my solution:

[image]

Whenever I have an unhandled exception, my app redirects me to the Error page, as expected.  But, I lose the exception information, because, I'm assuming, the app is redirecting.  I even tried `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"` in the customErrors element, but that didn't work.

So, here's my "Index" view on my Error controller, which the app is redirecting to- notice the model:

[image]

And further down, I have:

[image]

But, @Model is null.  How can I get the exception information from a customErrors redirect?

Comment: If you want to log the original exception, you need to do so before the redirect.

Comment: @Maess So therefore if I want exception details, I won't be able to use the customErrors redirect?

Comment: No, you just need to have your logging hooked in before the redirect, see the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get that model, you need to use the `HandleErrorAttribute` filter to catch the error.
You can see instructions here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/handleerrorattribute-or-error-handling-in-mvc-4/

TL;DR:

Disable the redirect, but make sure custom errors are still on:

```
<customErrors mode="On"/>
```

Make sure the `HandleErrorAttribute` filter is registered globally (it is by default):

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

Move/rename your error view to `~\Views\Shared\Error.cshtml`

Comment: I did this, but it's not sending me to the shared Error.cshtml page - it's returning the typical "Server error in /***** Application" yellow screen of death.

Comment: And I'll also say that I set a breakpoint in FilterConfig.cs (RegisterGlobalFilters), and it never gets hit.  I cleaned my solution, started from scratch, it doesn't get hit.

Comment: Are you certain the filter is registered globally? In ASP.NET MVC 4+, the `RegisterGlobalFilters` method should be defined in `App_Start\FilterConfig.cs` and in Global.asax.cs, there should be a call to it in `Application_Start`, like this: `FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);`

Comment: Yes, I checked, everything checks out like you say. :(

Comment: Is `Application_Start` being called at all? If not, the app might not be restarting properly...

Comment: No, it is not.  I will investigate.  Thanks for all your help

Comment: Sometimes, the IIS app pool is kept active. You can try killing it manually to make sure it is restarted and that Application_Start is called.

Comment: Will HTTP errors (404, etc.) be routed to my Error page, or is it just exceptions?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. To handle a 404, you could use a custom error (`<error statusCode="404" redirect="/error/notfound" />`), but then it's a redirect, so you lose information. For alternatives, check out the answers to this other question (beware, some are old answers for ASP.NET MVC 1 or 2): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc